# How to show data from app to Today Extension Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, today-extension

I have a app with data stored in core data but I also need to pass that data to my today extension. I was trying to do it with core data but it doesn't work. 
Maybe I would have to user userdefaults to pass the data from the app to the today extension.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to enable and use [Application Group Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think target only missing.

Try like this

Add today extension target membership for .xcodeModalId

Step: Click on your model file, and select both targets under 'Target Membership' on right-hand panel

Comment: When I added both targets then put in the Core Data code then it said that App Delegate was use of undeclared type.

Comment: have to add target for AppDelegate too.